# Over securing an app with user permission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, business-logic

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following nested model:

```
# country.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :states

# state.rb
belongs_to :country
has_many :cities

# city.rb
belongs_to :state
```

As usual, there will be a `user_id` in `Country`. The business logic is a user can add a country, and that country record belongs to the user as the owner. Then in each country, the user can add states, and a each state can have cities. All these can only be entered by the owner.

Now I am using the `CanCan` gem to check if a country belongs to a user. If the user is the owner, then he can subsequently add states and cities.

Question: Should I also check if the state/city is being added to a country which belongs to a user? Logically, the form should have already checked the country belongs to user, but should I check the subsequent levels?

Comment: Rule of thumb: do not trust user input. If a user can submit a request with a State that they do not own (by modifying  javascript, trying random state id, etc...), then you have to the check server side, in your controller.